# Keeping remote files synced with local files?

Tags: svn

When developing web applications, how does one keep local files and remote files synced together? There is the obvious way, whenever you edit a file on your local machine, just upload that file to the remote machine. Is there a more efficient way? I ask because I have been using subversion control, and it is so easy to keep files synced on a remote server. All I have to do is "commit" and it will find the files which need to be replaced.

Comment: Are you on Mac OS X, Linux, or Windows? That changes the answer to your question.

Comment: One option: use Subversion control, keep a working copy on the webserver, and trigger it up to update once you make a change, or every minute. Of course that requires `svn` to be installed on the webserver.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using rsync for that purposes. Works on Windows, Mac, and Unix/Linux. A little bit hard with file permissions on Windows, but after few hours of digging I managed to do it right. Very fast when synchronizing file trees.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

**Software**

Web development suites for Mac OS X like [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) and [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/) have automatic FTP upload functions, where you can click a button and all the changed files in your local server upload replace the old ones in the remote server.

For Windows: Although there is no direct equivalent of these programs, [Aptana](https://github.com/aptana/studio3) is an IDE that has FTP-upload functions, or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) could  work with it's `ftp_synchronize` plugin.

**Symlinks**

You could also set up a symlink between your local webserver root and a mounted FTP folder in your file structure like this:

`ln -s ~/path/to/local/server ~/path/to/FTP/client/`

Then, every time you change anything in the local folder, it is automatically placed/replaced into the FTP folder you have mounted. (On Windows, use `mklink /d` instead of `ln -s`).

**Scripts**

Additionally, if you wanted to, you could write a script (Applescript on a Mac, or VBscript on Windows) that uploads the files, however, this could get complicated and would require advanced knowledge of the scripting language of your OS.

Comment: Under the software category, is there anything for Windows that does that?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows is rather lacking in this area, as most good web development apps are made for Mac OS X. However, check out this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869886/pc-equivalent-of-coda), and see if there's something there you would like.

Answer (score 0):

On a PC, provided the destination (web server file system) is accessible as a UNC path or drive letter you can use any one of a number of backup programs to do this.